# Using logstash Elasticsearch output plugin error: NameError: SSLConnectionSocketFactory not found

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, search, logstash

I am trying to import data from MySQL to Elasticsearch using logstash version.

Versions of software used:

- Java/JRE 1.8
- Elasticsearch 6.1.0
- Logstash 6.1.0

My conf contents are as follows:

**file: simple-out.conf**

```
input {
    jdbc {
        # MySQL jdbc connection string to our database, mydb
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://valid/validDBNAME?useSSL=false"
        # The user we wish to execute our statement as
        jdbc_user => "MY USER"
        jdbc_password => "MY PWD"
        # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\JavaDevelopment\TomcatServer\apache-tomcat-8.5.20\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar"
        # The name of the driver class for Postgresql
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        # our query
        statement => "SELECT * from testtable"
        jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
        jdbc_page_size => "50000"
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
    elasticsearch {     
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
        index => "test-migrate" 
        document_type => "data" 
    }
}
```

When I run logstash I get the following error:

```
[2017-12-19T16:50:08,055][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<NameError: SSLConnectionSocketFactory not found ERROR
```

Please suggest how to get past this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `httpclient-VERSION.jar`, `httpcore-VERSION.jar` files to `LOGSTASH_HOME/vendor/jruby/lib/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, the solution is:
add LOGSTASH_HOME variable path in environment variables in mycomputer properities to C:\some_path\logstash-6.3.0
then add these files to C:\some_path\logstash-6.3.0\logstash-core\lib\jars
**files:**
httpclient-4.5.2.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
httpcore-VERSION.jar

this is because logstash doesn't come with ssl jar file and you need to add this to jar folder and set the environment so as logstash can read those jar files 
and try using gitbash rather than cmd or powershell!
and try to close and restart your logstash and elasticsearch
follow this link to see which index are comming to elasticsearch. 
http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v
if you are running on diff. port please change port number

**addidional tips**
and it didn't work for me on jdk 10.x so use jdk 8.x
and maybe installer wont work even so just unzip file and run elasticsearch.bat and logstash -f cong_filepath\configfile.config in bin folders

 windows user can type cmd in top of path 
Please make sure MySQL is running, (doesn't mean open) on server

Learn @ https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin

**To resolve it yourself in future:**
open logstash/bin folder and right click and gitbash (need git)

 type "vi log" and press tab 3 times till all logstahsh files are shown up
a new line will appear, type "vi logstash" and press enter to open source file
you'll have code to understand flow,.. if you look carefully Logstash_home and javacmd (at bottom) are important that execute jar, javacmd should be set to your java_home variable in env variables to jdk8.x and Logstash_home has a path for jar directory, either change it or put you jar to this folder.
Hope this helps!